# How to communicate between USBDriverKit driver and Client app?

Tags: macos, ipados, driverkit

We are experimenting with DriverKit on macOS while DriverKit is still in beta on iPadOS. We want to build a Driver for iPad that will allow to communicate our iPad App with USB device.

What we did:

1. Configured and implemented a driver that uses `USBDriverKit::IOUSBHostInterface` as provider. This driver is automatically matched/started by macOS when we plug our device into USB port. Next we utilised `USBDriverKit::IOUSBHostPipe` to send/receive data from our device. We print data from device in logs for now.
2. Studied [Communicating Between a DriverKit Extension and a Client App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/communicating_between_a_driverkit_extension_and_a_client_app)
3. Configured and implemented a driver that based on `IOUserClient` and allows to open communication channel by macOs App using `IOServiceOpen` API. Driver has callback to pass data to macOS Client App.

Currently we want to combine 2 drivers and pass data received from USB device to our client App using callback. Unfortunately, we stuck since now we have 2 instances of driver:

1. First instance is automatically run by macOS when device is plugged
2. Second instance is created when we are connecting from Client App and `virtual kern_return_t NewUserClient(uint32_t type, IOUserClient** userClient)` method is called.

So we can't use second instance to do USB device communication since it has wrong provider(IOUserClient) in `kern_return_t Start(IOService * provider)` but we need `IOUSBHostInterface` to start:

```
    ivars->interface = OSDynamicCast(IOUSBHostInterface, provider);
    if(ivars->interface == NULL) {
        ret = kIOReturnNoDevice;
        goto Exit;
    }
```

Are we doing it wrong? Maybe instead of automatic matching for `IOUSBHostInterface` we should do it manually from UserClient driver or use another approach?

As we learned we have to create a new service instance in `NewUserClient` method and can't return driver that was run by OS:

```
kern_return_t IMPL(MyDriver, NewUserClient)
{
    kern_return_t ret = kIOReturnSuccess;
    IOService* client = nullptr;
    ret = Create(this, "UserClientProperties", &client);

    if (ret != kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        goto Exit;
    }

    *userClient = OSDynamicCast(IOUserClient, client);

    if (*userClient == NULL)
    {
        client->release();
        ret = kIOReturnError;
        goto Exit;
    }
Exit:
    return ret;
}
```

BTW, maybe there is much easier way to forward data from USB device to iPadOS App?

Comment: Can you please provide the contents of the driver's Info.plist file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about USBDriverKit and iPadOS, but perhaps my limited experience with PCIDriverKit on macOS can server as a useful analogue.

I have implemented a DEXT for a custom PCI device, and a user space application that communicates with the driver to do things with the device.

The DEXT consists of two classes (two pairs of `.iig` and `.cpp` files):

- `class MyDriver: public IOService`
- `class MyDriverClient: public IOUserClient`

with the following `Info.plist`:

```
<dict>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>MyDriver</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifierKernel</key <string>com.apple.kpi.iokit</string>
            <key>IOClass</key> <string>IOUserService</string>
            <key>IOPCIMatch</key> <string>0xcafebabe</string>
            <key>IOPCITunnelCompatible</key> <true/>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key> <string>IOPCIDevice</string>
            <key>IOUserClass</key> <string>MyDriver</string>
            <key>IOUserServerName</key> <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            <key>MyDriverClientProperties</key>
            <dict>
                <key>IOClass</key>
                <string>IOUserUserClient</string>
                <key>IOUserClass</key>
                <string>MyDriverClient</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

When the system discovers a PCI device with matching vendor/device ID as per the `IOPCIMatch` property value, it:

1. Instantiates an `IOUserService` class (as mandated by the `IOClass` property) in the kernel to facilitate the communication with the DEXT residing in userspace
2. Spawns the userspace process for the DEXT.
3. Instantiates the required provider class in that process (here: an `IOPCIDevice` as per the `IOProviderClass` property).
4. Instantiates the main class (here: `MyDriver` as per the `IOUserClass` property), giving it a pointer to the `provider` created above.

As part of its `Start` implementation, `MyDriver` invokes [`RegisterService()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/ioservice/3180701-registerservice) to make itself appear in the I/O Registry (e.g. `ioreg -l`).

When a userspace application (with appropriate entitlements) later finds the registered `MyDriver` service (e.g. using [`IOServiceGetMatchingService()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514535-ioservicegetmatchingservice?language=objc)), and opens it ( [`IOServiceOpen()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514515-ioserviceopen?changes=la___4_6_5&language=objc)), on the DEXT side that ends up invoking `MyDriver::NewUserClient()` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325581-newuserclient)), which looks like this:

```
kern_return_t IMPL(MyDriver, NewUserClient)
{
    kern_return_t ret = kIOReturnSuccess;
    IOService* client = nullptr;

    ret = Create(this, "MyDriverClientProperties", &client);
    // ... Error handling

    *userClient = OSDynamicCast(IOUserClient, client);
    // ... Error handling

    // If you need to remember/keep track of the client, you could stash it in the `ivars`, already casted to its true type:
    ivars->client = OSDynamicCast(MyDriverClient, client);

    // ...
}
```

What exactly [`Create`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325579-create) will do is determined by the provided property dictionary (under the arbitrarily named `MyDriverClientProperties` key in the `Info.plist`). In this case, an `IOUserUserClient` *(the double-`User` is not a typo)* object is created in the kernel (`IOClass` property), and a `MyDriverClient` object is created in userspace (`IOUserClass` property).

Your description in the question seems to suggest otherwise, but at least in my case, the client object is fed the `MyDriver` instance as its `provider`, and I am able to obtain a reference to it:

```
kern_return_t IMPL(MyDriverClient, Start)
{
    kern_return_t ret;
    ret = Start(provider, SUPERDISPATCH);
    // ... Error handling

    ivars->driver = OSDynamicCast(MyDriver, provider);
    // ... Error handling

    // ...
}
```

Later, when for example `MyDriverClient::ExternalMethod` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/iouserclient/3325619-externalmethod)) is invoked, I can use `ivars->driver` to invoke functionalities of the `MyDriver` class and interact with the underlying device.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer covers your main question well - there aren't 2 drivers, you just create an instance of a user client class within the same driver when the app connects.

However, for completeness I'll add an answer to this part:

> BTW, maybe there is much easier way to forward data from USB device to iPadOS App?

No, on macOS you could use the user space USB API, but this isn't available on iPadOS. The only way to talk to USB devices on iPadOS is via a DriverKit driver, or by signing up for Apple's MFi programme. (The latter is also available for iPhones and pre-M1 iPads.)